# How to give multiple values in fileNamePattern in ice:inputFile

Tags: jsf, file-upload, icefaces, file-type

I would like to know how to give multiple values in fileNamePattern in ice:inputFile, I need to add csv and txt file formats as the acceptable ones. But I am not allowed to give two values. I have tried giving **".+.txt",".+.csv"** but it didnt help.suggestions please.

```
<ice:inputFile label="Upload" immediate="true"
submitOnUpload="postUpload" id="filename"
file="#{importAnalysisResultsModelBean.uploadFile}"
style="width:395px;" buttonClass="button"
fileNamePattern=".+\.txt"
uploadDirectory="#{globalController.uploadDirectory}/ssc/"
uploadDirectoryAbsolute="true"
actionListener="#{importAnalysisResultsBackingBean.importActionListener}" />
```

Comment: Your initial question tags are very confusing. Are you using JSP or Facelets (XHTML)? Are you using ICEfaces 2.x or ICEfaces 3.x? You tagged them all which makes no utter sense. I've at least fixed the insane tagging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered this works best for me :

```
fileNamePattern="(.+\.csv)|(.+\.xls)|(.+\.xml)|(.+\.html)|(.+\.htm)"
```